# flutter - use theme in application

Tags: flutter, widget, themes

I have the following code to have a specific theme in a part of my application:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
        )
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Hello', ),
```

I want to use the bodyText2 I defined to the text 'Hello' to have the color green. In fact I want the text have the style name 'bodyText2' and the corresponding style (color green in that case).
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options you can try for your app:

1. Define [a global theme](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes) at your `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Sample App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the default TextTheme. Use this to specify the default
    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green), // Define your default Text style
      subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.green), // Define your own subtitle style
    ),
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sample title', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1)), // Use your config like this
      body: Text('Sample content'), // Without specifying style, the app will auto use your bodyText2 config
  ),
);
```

2. Define a [DefaultTextTheme](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-defaulttextstyle-examples) at your local widget level:

```
Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'The first text', // A green color text
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

A very good example on `DefaultTextTheme` [can be found here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-defaulttextstyle-examples).

You can take a quick look through the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) for how to config a `Text` quickly.